# WPF, Datagrid Custom DataGridTextColumn DependencyProperty not working

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, dependency-properties

I have following custom `Datagrid`:

```
<ZF:ZFDataGrid
    x:Name="dgvGrid"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top"
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
    CanUserAddRows="True"
    CanUserDeleteRows="False"
    CanUserResizeRows="False"
    CanUserReorderColumns="False"
    CanUserSortColumns="False"
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
    SelectionUnit="Cell"
    SelectionMode="Single"
    ItemsSource="{Binding POSModel}">

       <ZF:DataGridNumericColumn 
            Header="Qty" 
            Width="80"
            AllowDecimalSign="{Binding   Path=IsUseDecimal}"/>

</ZF:ZFDataGrid>
```

I have used MVVM Pattern.
`IsUseDecimal` is a `boolean` property.
And, I created `DependencyProperty` name `AllowDecimalSign`. If I change the value of `IsUseDecimal`, then I want `AllowDecimalSign` to become that value too. But, it's not working.

```
    public class DataGridNumericColumn : DataGridTextColumn
    {
        private static readonly Regex NonnumericChars = new Regex(@"\D");
        private static readonly Regex NonnumericCharsExceptFirstMinus = 
            new Regex(@"(?<!^[^-]*)-|[^\d-]");

        public static readonly DependencyProperty AllowDecimalSignProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "AllowDecimalSign",
                typeof(bool),
                typeof(DataGridNumericColumn),
                new PropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(ValueChangedCallBack)));

    public static void ValueChangedCallBack(DependencyObject property, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
            {
            }
        public bool AllowDecimalSign
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(AllowDecimalSignProperty); }
            set { SetValue(AllowDecimalSignProperty, value); }
        }

        protected override object PrepareCellForEdit(FrameworkElement editingElement, RoutedEventArgs editingEventArgs)
        {
            var textBox = (TextBox) editingElement;
            textBox.PreviewTextInput += OnPreviewTextInput;
            textBox.PreviewLostKeyboardFocus += OnPreviewLostKeyboardFocus;
            DataObject.AddPastingHandler(textBox, this.OnPaste);
            return base.PrepareCellForEdit(editingElement, editingEventArgs);
        }

        private void OnPreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
        {
            var textBox = (TextBox)sender;

///WHY this.AllowDecimalSign always False ??? 

            if (this.AllowDecimalSign && e.Text == "." && textBox.Text.Contains("."))
                e.Handled = true;

            if (this.AllowDecimalSign && e.Text == ".")
                return;

            if (!this.IsNumeric(e.Text))
                e.Handled = true;
        }

        private void OnPreviewLostKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var textBox = (TextBox) sender;
            textBox.Text = this.ExtractNumericParts(textBox.Text);
        }

        private void OnPaste(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
        {
            if(!e.SourceDataObject.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text, true))
                return;

            var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
            var preSelection = textBox.Text.Substring(0, textBox.SelectionStart);
            var postSelection = textBox.Text.Substring(textBox.SelectionStart 
                + textBox.SelectionLength);
            var pastedText = (string)e.SourceDataObject.GetData(DataFormats.Text);

            if (!this.IsNumeric(preSelection + pastedText + postSelection))
                e.CancelCommand();
        }

        private bool IsNumeric(string text)
        {
            var result = false;

            if(AllowDecimalSign)
            {
                decimal number;
                result = decimal.TryParse(text, out number);

                if (!this.AllowNegativeValues)
                    return result && number >= 0;
            }
            else
            {
                int number;
                result = Int32.TryParse(text, out number);

                if (!this.AllowNegativeValues)
                    return result && number >= 0;
            }

            return result;
        }

        private string ExtractNumericParts(string text)
        {
            if (this.IsNumeric(text))
                return text;

            text = this.RemoveIllegalChars(text);

            return this.TrimDigitsToInt32Range(text);
        }

        private string RemoveIllegalChars(string text)
        {
            var illegalChars = this.AllowNegativeValues 
                ? NonnumericCharsExceptFirstMinus 
                : NonnumericChars;
            return illegalChars.Replace(text, string.Empty);
        }

        private string TrimDigitsToInt32Range(string numericText)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(numericText))
                return "0";

            return this.IsNumeric(numericText)
                ? numericText
                : this.TrimDigitsToInt32Range(
                    numericText.Remove(numericText.Length - 1));
        }
    }
```

The value of `AllowDecimalSign` is always `false` and doesn't reflect the value of `IsUseDecimal`, even when I also used this code:

```
AllowDecimalSign="{Binding Path=IsUseDecimal, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

Comment: Have you tried checking with your debugger if your `ValueChangedCallBack` is ever hit? Do you see any binding errors in the output window? Maybe also try inspecting the property value with Snoop.

Comment: if i change the value to <ZF:DataGridNumericColumn 
            Header="Qty" 
            Width="80"
            AllowDecimalSign="True"/>, then the value will change

Comment: if i use checkbox to change the value, also not work. 
AllowDecimalSign="{Binding ElementName=chkUseDecimal, Path=IsChecked}">

Comment: i put breakpoint public static void ValueChangedCallBack(DependencyObject property, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args), but never been called. except manually give value AllowDecimalSign="True" or "False"

Comment: `IsUseDecimal` is a property in your ViewModel or inside the items of your DataGrid? I assume it's VM's (or whatever DataContext your DataGrid has), right?

Comment: yeah, IsUseDecimal is my property in my VM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bindings don't work with DataGridColumns of any kind, I'm afraid. They don't have a DataContext, and they're not part of the visual tree.

For Bindings in columns to work, you'll have to resort to proxy items for setting the DataContext, or other similar workarounds.

[I explained the proxy item approach here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30775850/databinding-issue-while-using-multidatatrigger/30777174#30777174), for the `VisualBrush` class in that case, but it should work the same for `DataGridColumn`.

**I'm assuming `IsUseDecimal` is a property in your ViewModel** (or whatever DataContext the DataGrid has).

Proxy element:

```
    public class DataContextProxy: Freezable
    {
        public DataContextProxy()
        {
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, DataContextProperty, new Binding());
        }

        public object DataContext
        {
            get { return GetValue(DataContextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DataContextProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty DataContextProperty = FrameworkElement
            .DataContextProperty.AddOwner(typeof (DataContextProxy));

        protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
        {
            return new DataContextProxy();
        }
    }
```

And add it to Resources and use it in your Column:

```
<ZF:ZFDataGrid
    x:Name="dgvGrid"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top"
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
    CanUserAddRows="True"
    CanUserDeleteRows="False"
    CanUserResizeRows="False"
    CanUserReorderColumns="False"
    CanUserSortColumns="False"
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
    SelectionUnit="Cell"
    SelectionMode="Single"
    ItemsSource="{Binding POSModel}">
   <ZF:ZFDataGrid.Resources>
       <behavior:DataContextProxy x:Key="Proxy"
                                  DataContext="{Binding}" />
   </ZF:ZFDataGrid.Resources>
   <ZF:ZFDataGrid.Columns>
       <ZF:DataGridNumericColumn 
            Header="Qty" 
            Width="80"
            AllowDecimalSign="{Binding Path=DataContext.IsUseDecimal,
                                       Source={StaticResource Proxy}}"/>
   </ZF:ZFDataGrid.Columns>
</ZF:ZFDataGrid>
```

Comment: i cannot call  <ZF:DataGridNumericColumn 
            DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Proxy},
                                  Path=DataContext}" , datacontext not available... and what is <behavior:DataContextProxy x:Key="Proxy"
                                  DataContext="{Binding}" /> ??

Comment: Yup, sorry, you're right, DataGridColumns don't have DataContext, I'll edit my answer. As for `<behavior:DataContextProxy>`, it's the class I copied right above. You just have to add its namespace to the namespace definitions of your view (in my case that was `behavior` but yours could be different, like `ZF` in your example)